# Can we build a zero knowledge mapping using public-key encryption?

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm trying to understand if this design is possible. I want to build a mapping that is zero-knowledge, between a `(pubkey, proposalId) => bytes` form, without revealing the key.

Let's say we build a ZK circuit with private inputs `(pubkey, proposalId)`, and the public input (`sig`), where `sig = sign(H(pubkey, proposalId), pubkey)`. It's my understanding that if you sign with a public key, it's effectively public-key encryption, where you can only decrypt with the private key.

If the circuit logic verified that you could decrypt the sig, and hence  the commit to `(pubkey, proposalId)` was valid, then you could use `sig` as a key in the ZK mapping. Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: Can you formally define "zero knowledge mapping"?

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau I've realised a more correct description is just a one-to-one mapping between a public-key and a value, without revealing the public-key.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to reveal the public key? That's the very purpose of a public key...

Comment: So if I get it right, what you want has nothing to do with zero-knowledge, you just want a one-way permutation?

Comment: Thank you @GeoffroyCouteau - that is exactly the term I was searching for. Will edit/update the question.

Comment: Am I missing an edit here?